# Accessing an objects property inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'm trying to access objects properties inside an array in my code to render the text values of input boxes restored after a refresh from the local storage but for some reason when I try to run the for loop inside my appStart() function it gives me: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at appStart". Any insiights of why this happens and how to fix it will be greatly appreciated.

```
const currentDayPlaceholder = $("#currentDay");
const timeInTimeBlocks = $(".input-group-text");
const timeBlockInput = $(".form-control");
const saveButton = $(".saveBtn");
let numericCurrentTime = parseInt(moment().format("H A"));
let notes = [];


currentDayPlaceholder.append(moment().format('dddd, MMMM Do'));

function timeBlocksColorDeterminator() {

    for (let i = 0; i < timeInTimeBlocks.length; i++) {

        let numericTimeinTimeBlock = parseInt($(timeInTimeBlocks[i]).text());
        if ($(timeInTimeBlocks[i]).hasClass('pm')) {
            numericTimeinTimeBlock += 12;
        }
        if (numericCurrentTime === numericTimeinTimeBlock) {
            $(timeBlockInput[i]).addClass("present");
        } else if (numericCurrentTime > numericTimeinTimeBlock) {
            $(timeBlockInput[i]).addClass("past");
        } else {
            $(timeBlockInput[i]).addClass("future");
        }

    }
}

function appStart() {

    notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("timeBlockNotes"));

    for (let i = 0; i < timeBlockInput.length; i++) {
        if (i === parseInt(notes[i].id)) {
            timeBlockInput[i].value = notes[i].value;
        }
    }
}
appStart();

saveButton.on("click", function () {
    console.log("click");
    notes.push({
        value: timeBlockInput[this.id].value,
        id: this.id
    })
    localStorage.setItem("timeBlockNotes", JSON.stringify(notes));
})

timeBlocksColorDeterminator();
```

Comment: At a glance I’d say you have an `undefined` entry in your notes array: `[undefined]`. notes[i] produces undefined and throws when you try to access id from it. Either that or timeBlockInput.length > notes.length.

Comment: print notes[i] value in console like as,

    console.log(notes[i]);

& check have property id in note[i] or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this after changing my appStart() function to this :

```
function appStart() {

    notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("timeBlockNotes"));

    for (let i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {

        timeBlockInput[parseInt(notes[i].id)].value = notes[i].value;

    }
}
```

thank you guys for your comments and answers.